# jsl tag doesn't show up when parsing HTML with Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, jsl

A little background (I am super novice at programming, so bear with me):

I am trying to scrape duration_in_traffic numbers from google maps (I know there is an API, but this data piece is restricted to 'Maps for Business' so I figured this would be the easiest route).

When I use Beautiful Soup to find all the `<div>` tags, hardly anything shows up. After inspecting the element a bit closer, it looks like the majority of the page is nested under a tag that looks like:

```
<jsl jstcache="79"></jsl>
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the javascript and the dynamic nature of the page, but is there even a way to access the divisions under this jsl tag using Beautiful Soup?

Answer (score 0):

If Beautifulsoup can't do it, I can recommend lxml.html [0]

[0] http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html